# Ubuntu 14.04 wireless unstable and the signal is weak

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, signal

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside Win8.1 and the wireless was unstable. I updated windows network drivers then it went better but the signal is still very weak and also sometimes network switches off like before.

Running this command:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

resulted in:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12103971/

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Comment: I found the solution in my answer here but I still don't quite know what the code did. If you have any clue that would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a hell alot of trial-error, this fixed it for good! :D

```
sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
sudo sh -c "echo 'options ath5k nohwcrypt' >/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf"
```

Comment: If it does anything at all, it is an accident. If you run: `modinfo ath5k`, you will see that one of the available driver parameters is: `parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)`. Application of the parameter disables hardware (on chip) encryption and moves it to software; i.e. wpa_supplicant. However, as you also see, it requires a boolean operator to be effective (bool). I suggest you amend the file you created to change to: `options ath5k nohwcrypt=Y`. If you need guidance on how to do so, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Yeah you're right. It seems like a confirmed bug :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+bug/1311257?comments=all

This helped people fixing it (worked with me too): 
`sudo killall wpa_supplicant` .
About your suggestion, yeah further explanation would be great.

Comment: Edit the file: `gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf`. Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the line to: `options ath5k nohwcrypt=Y`  Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot.