# How to make Cudy AC650S wifi adapter with Realtek 8821CU chipset work on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 20.04

I have been trying to get my Cudy AC650S wifi adapter work on Ubuntu 20.04 (Kernel 5.4.0-51) and have failed so far, after trying all the solutions I could find online. That's why I'm asking here now.
It seems that the drivers Cudy provides only work with Ubuntu 18.04 and not 20.04 (https://www.linux.org/threads/installing-a-usb-wifi-unit-in-ubuntu-20-04.29202/page-2).
So I installed these drivers from Github: https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU
The system does seem to recognise the adapter. when I use `inxi -n` this is the output:

```
Network: Device-1: Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235 driver: iwlwifi
IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: c4:85:08:41:69:b4
Device-2: Realtek 802.11ac NIC type: USB driver: usb-network
```

It also shows up on `lsusb`

However, it does not show as a network device, when I check on `lshw -class network`. That's all the output I get:

```
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 24
   serial: c4:85:08:41:69:b4
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-51-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:32 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Similarly, on `iw dev` it shows only:

```
Interface wlp2s0
    ifindex 2
    wdev 0x1
    addr c4:85:08:41:69:b4
    ssid Vodafone-9994
    type managed
    channel 11 (2462 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2462 MHz
    txpower 15.00 dBm
```

I'm a bit lost now, what the problem could be. Did the driver installation not work properly? Or is there something else I could do to "activate" the adapter?

As you can probably see, I'm a newbie with Ubuntu, but so far always managed to solve my problems with the tips provided here and elsewhere. But this I have run out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated!

Update:
Hier is the result of `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b330 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus 720p CMOS webcam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And for `sudo modprobe 8821cu` I've been getting this error message:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8821cu': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I wonder why any USB wireless device with its necessarily tiny antenna could outperform the usually reliable Intel 6235. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :).
I had some problems with video-conferencing and  thought that having a 802.11ac chip might help with that.

Comment: I would much rather troubleshoot the Intel; but, if you insist, please show us: `lsusb` and also the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe 8821cu` Have you tried these troubleshooting steps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/662313/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-unstable-and-the-signal-is-weak/662484#662484

Comment: Thanks, I added the outputs. But if you think it's not worth it trying to make it work because it wouldn't help much with the connection speed, I'd defer to your judgement of course.